# Pass array of strings to React component with string coming from json file and allow inline span tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, preact

I'm trying to get an array of strings to display as paragraphs and allow an inline span tag inside of these strings.

My issue comes is when the value is added inside the paragraph the decodes the "<" and ">" tag start and ends to their decoded values "<" and ">"

Is there an easy way to get this working without making a specific component for this case?

My React component is as follows

```
const Paragraphs = ({ data, languageText }) => {
    if (data) {
        const texts = languageText[data.languageKey];

        return (
            <section>
                {texts && texts.map(text => <p>{text}</p>)}
            </section>
        );
    } else {
        console.warn(`webpage::element: 'PARAGRAPHS' lack content`);
    }
}
export default Paragraphs;
```

this is the array that is passed to texts

```
[
"When a Relic is found or assembled from Relic Fragments, a payout is rewarded, based on its rarity. <span style=\"font-weight: bold\">The rarer the item, the higher the payout!</span>",
"In addition to Relics, Gold Coins can also be found."
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, React escapes HTML to prevent XSS just use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, take a look at [oficial docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: So this is the correct answer and is unsafe to do so and is not reccomended. If need you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTMLbut not recommended as you can inject scripts this way