# How do I put a link in a string template?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

Not sure if this is even a thing, but I have been trying to put a link inside a JS string template.

I have an object that gets passed to a react component. One of the properties is `text`:

```
const someData = {
text: `blah blah blah call <a href="tel:+111222333444"></a> for more information`
}
```

I want to pass this to the component as props and render it:

`<SomeComponent>{props.text}</SomeComponent>`

and have that `<a>` el render within the string as a live link, same as if it were explicitly put on the DOM.

I have tried assigning the `<a/>` to a variable and interpolating it, i have tried creating a small function that returns a DOM node of an `<a>` (same as I have created many components) and calling that function in the interpolated string - both methods print the actual DOM node as text. I have googled a bit and seen some dangerouslySetInnerHTML hacks, however they all seem to still involve embedding that node in the middle of a string, dangerous or not, and that is not working for me. Any help appreciated or clarification if this can even be done or not :)

Comment: Cant do this with a string otherwise you could inject code. I think you would need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283506/pass-array-of-strings-to-react-component-with-string-coming-from-json-file-and-a

Comment: Thanks Derek, the link to the react docs in that post helped a lot. I was implementing the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` incorrectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'blah blah blah call <a href="tel:+111222333444"></a> for more information'};
}

function SomeComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: this is correct, but for anyone who may see this can you add the `const someData = {
text: SomeComponent()
}` just for completeness should they be passing the data on an obj as props like i am lol :)